# How to convert an array to string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this -

```
var arr = ['This', 'is', 'array']
```

I want the string output like this -

```
"This is array"
```

Comment: What is the problem you experienced when doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just simply use `join()` method of array -

```
const string = arr.join(' ');
```